# About the Bonferroni Inequality

Tags: probability

I am a first year undergrad self-studying probability over the summer, and I am having difficulty understanding the second equation below. I looked up and found only about the first equation but not the second one.

The Bonferroni Inequality states that for all events $A_1,\dots,A_n$
$$Pr\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^n Pr(A_i) \qquad and \qquad Pr\left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) \geq 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n Pr(A_i^c)$$

The first one takes into account of non-disjoint events, but I have no idea about the second one. Any help (proofs) would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with DeMorgan's law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i)^c = \bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^c)$. Then bound this in the same way as the first inequality and finish the proof by using that $Pr(A^c) = 1 - Pr(A)$.

Comment: Oh thank you so much !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry I am having difficulty with "Then bound this in the same way as the first inequality " :(  and just to confirm, did you use the morgan's for the first equation in your post? Thanks

Comment: You can bound $Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n (A_i^c)\right)$ the same way you bounded $Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)$

Comment: Emm if I understand you correctly, $Pr\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right)^c = Pr\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i^c\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n A_i^c$. Then using $Pr(A^c) = 1-Pr(A)$ we have $1-Pr\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n A_i^c $ which rearranged is the second equation.. Thanks!!!!!!!!